# CakePHP - Render a view that is actually plugin's view from Component

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

Morning guys,

So this is my first time developing a plugin for CakePHP. Here's what I am doing in `startUp` of the component.

```
//component
function startUp(&$controller){
    //....
    if($render){
        $controller->render("return", "ajax");
    }
}
```

By default render will look at `app/views/<controllers>/return.ctp` and `app/views/layouts/ajax` for this render call.

Is there anyway that I can give a directive to render from `app/my_plugin/views/awesome_stuffs/return.ctp` and `app/my_plugin/views/layout/ajax.ctp` instead?

I believe the third `param` of `Controller::render($file, $layout, $file)` could do the job, but is there any better Cake way of doing things?

Plus, is that considered a good practice to take over controller's rendering function like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to call the PLUGIN controller/action URL in your AJAX call, instead of the main app controller/action URL.

ex:
instead of:

```
http://domain.com/controller/action
```

you call:

```
http://domain.com/my_plugin/controller/action
```

When you do it this way, the plugin views & layouts are called automagically. See:

http://book.cakephp.org/view/1118/Plugin-Tips

http://book.cakephp.org/view/1115/Plugin-Views

Otherwise, the only way I know of is manually setting paths as you mentioned or controller-wide via:

```
var $viewPath = 'path/to/plugin/views/';
var $layoutPath = 'path/to/plugin/layouts/';
```

Comment: the $layoutPath is only for setting a sub-folder in the controller's views/layouts/ folder AFAIK

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try setting $this->view to the plugin dotted view file you want to render.

Answer (score 0):

add to your source

```
$controller->plugin = "pluginname";
```

Comment: Welcome around here. Can you explain and/or cite a source as to why this helps?